# Empty Top Option in a Struts 2 Iteration Select

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts2

Is there any way to add an Empty Top Select option in the following:

```xml
<select id="OrderNameIssueId" name="OrderWork.OrderNameIssueId" style="width: auto">
    <s:iterator value="OrderWork.ClientOrderNameIssues" status="rowIdx" id="ClientIssueOption">
        <option value='<s:property value="#ClientIssueOption.OrderNameIssue.OrderNameIssueId"/>' <s:if test="OrderWork.OrderNameIssueId != null && (OrderWork.OrderNameIssueId == #ClientIssueOption.OrderNameIssue.OrderNameIssueId)">selected</s:if><s:else></s:else>>
            <s:property value="#ClientIssueOption.OrderNameIssue.issueDescription"/>
            <s:if test="#ClientIssueOption.ApprovedOption == true">&nbsp;|&nbsp;Approved</s:if>
            <s:else>
                <s:if test="#ClientIssueOption.RequireFix == true">&nbsp;|&nbsp;Requires Fix</s:if>
                <s:else>&#9;|&nbsp;Unapproved</s:else>
            </s:else>
            &nbsp;|&nbsp;Format:&nbsp;<s:property value="#ClientIssueOption.OrderNameIssue.issueHint"/>
        </option>
    </s:iterator>
</select>
```

It is on a JSP page that uses Struts 2.
The select itself works, however we need to have an option that will show up on the page like so:

```
<option value="0">--</option>
```

Comment: And what stops you from adding `<option value="0">--</option>` before `<s:iterator>`?

Comment: @AleksandrM When doing just <option value="0">--</option> it became the only option in the drop down.

Comment: Then how come you've accepted answer that propose exactly that.

Comment: because the Answer provided was not just adding the one line, it included the If else which I was missing.

Comment: 1. `if else` doesn't change *it became the only option in the drop down* 2. How the answerer even knew about that custom logic of yours? What are they mind readers?

Comment: You could also use the emptyOption attribute or the headerKey/headerValue attributes of the Struts2 select tag - http://struts.apache.org/docs/select.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to add this below the "select" and above the     "s:iterator". You will also want to specify when selected.

```xml
<select id="OrderNameIssueId" name="OrderWork.OrderNameIssueId" style="width: auto">
    <s:if test="OrderWork.OrderNameIssueId == null || OrderWork.OrderNameIssueId == 0">
        <option value="0" selected>--Please select an option--</option>
    </s:if>
    <s:else>
        <option value="0">--Please select an option--</option>
    </s:else>
    <s:iterator value="OrderWork.ClientOrderNameIssues" status="rowIdx" id="ClientIssueOption">
       <option value='<s:property value="#ClientIssueOption.OrderNameIssue.OrderNameIssueId"/>' <s:if test="OrderWork.OrderNameIssueId != null && (OrderWork.OrderNameIssueId == #ClientIssueOption.OrderNameIssue.OrderNameIssueId)">selected</s:if><s:else></s:else>>
       <s:property value="#ClientIssueOption.OrderNameIssue.issueDescription"/>
       <s:if test="#ClientIssueOption.ApprovedOption == true">&nbsp;|&nbsp;Approved</s:if>
       <s:else>
           <s:if test="#ClientIssueOption.RequireFix == true">&nbsp;|&nbsp;Requires Fix</s:if>
           <s:else>&#9;|&nbsp;Unapproved</s:else>
       </s:else>
       &nbsp;|&nbsp;Format:&nbsp;<s:property value="#ClientIssueOption.OrderNameIssue.issueHint"/>
       </option>
   </s:iterator>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you! you are my life saver.